# Azure Data Factory Rest API - With AccountCode, APIKey & Token

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a use case wherein, I need to connect to an API for data request.

- The API requires a valid token to process the requests.
- To generate the token, I have a accountCode & secret key

**Assume BaseURL as**
BaseURL - [http://api.xxxxx.com/{accountCode}/data](http://api.xxxxx.com/%7BaccountCode%7D/data) (Value of account needs to be passed)

**Below script in Python/Java needs to be run to fetch the dateToken & token

- If we use Python 3.6 or above. Below is the code -**

--START-- {

```
import time

import requests

from hashlib import md5

account_code = "<account_name>"
key = "<api_key>"
actual_unix_time = int(time.time_ns() / 1000) # in milliseconds
TTL = 31536000000 # for 1 year
expiration_time = actual_unix_time + TTL
base_url = "https://api.xxxxx.com"
url = f"/{account_code}/data?fromDate=last6Hours&granularity=minute&type=ALL%2CVOD%2CLIVE&operation=reduceJoin&metrics=bufferratio"
pre_url = f"{url}&dateToken={expiration_time}"
token_generated = md5(f"{pre_url}{key}".encode('utf-8'))
token_value = token_generated.hexdigest()
request_url = f"{base_url}{pre_url}&token={token_value}"
response = requests.get(request_url)

print(response)
print(response.text)
```

} --END--

**- If we use Java. Below is the code -**

--START-- {

```
var key = pm.environment.get("NPAW-API-KEY"); 
var base_url = "https://api.xxxxx.com";

var url = pm.request.url.toString(); 
var path = url.replace(base_url, ''); 
var pre_url = pm.variables.replaceIn(path);

var moment = require('moment'); 
var actual_unix_time = moment().unix()*1000;

var TTL = 31536000000

var expiration_time = (actual_unix_time + TTL); 
var pre_url = pre_url+"&dateToken="+expiration_time;

var token_generated = CryptoJS.MD5(pre_url + key).toString();

var token_value = token_generated;

var request_url = (base_url+pre_url+'&token='+token_value).toString();
```

}--END--

Example of how the final URL - https://api.xxxxx.com/kb-vivek/data?fromDate=today&granularity=hour&type=ALL,VOD,LIVE&operation=reduceJoin&metrics=views,playtime&dateToken=1699016056000&token=7a9c97a4d4f108d1d32be2f7f8d00731

I tried to use Postman, wherein, I could pass the above script in the Pre-Request script and set environment variables for accountCode & Secret Key and I was able to achieve the result as desired.

**Question: How can I achieve this in Azure Data Factory?**

Comment: Can you please clarify this: You want to use the python/java script to get the account code and token (to build the URL)? And the query is how to do this in ADF?  Or the python code directly gives the required response, and you want to achieve that in ADF? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi @Saideep, Yes to get the dateToken & token- I need to use the code above. The same code also gives me an URL with date token & token which I can use to GET the required output.

Comment: So, do you want to implement this logic in ADF? Like build the URL with dateToken and token within ADF and call the URL? Or you just want to use the above script itself?

Comment: I want to build the URL and save it to a variable which I can use further to call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To achieve the requirement, we need to use a combination of set variables and dataflows (to generate md5 hex string and store final url in a file).
- First, I have created 4 parameters with values as shown below:

```
base_url: https://api.xxxxx.com
account_code: <account_name>
key: <api_key>
TTL: 31536000000
```

[image]

- First, I have created a variable to build `url`. I used the following dynamic content:

```
/@{pipeline().parameters.account_code}/data?fromDate=last6Hours&granularity=minute&type=ALL%2CVOD%2CLIVE&operation=reduceJoin&metrics=bufferratio
```

[image]

- Next, I have built the `pre_url` with the following dynamic content:

```
@{variables('url')}&dateToken=@{add(div(sub(ticks(utcNow()), ticks('1970-01-01')),10),31536000000)}
```

[image]

- Now, to encode the string and convert it to md5 hex string, I have used dataflow. I have passed `base_url, pre_url and key` to the dataflow from the pipeline.

[image]

- I have taken a sample csv file with only one row from blob storage (the data in this file does not matter but make sure it has 1 row only).

[image]

- I have created a derived column to create final URL by concatenating `base_url, pre_url and encoded md5 hex string`. Use the following content:

```
$base_url+$pre_url+'&token='+md5(encode(concat($pre_url,$key)))
```

[image]

- Now I am writing this data to a file by using `output to single file` option in the sink settings.

[image]

- When I debug the pipeline, the file will be written to my storage account. The contents of the file will be as shown below:

[image]

**NOTE:**

- Now since you want to generate date token once and use it for a year, I have written the data to a file.
- You run this pipeline once and generate a file with required URL (as above). Anytime you want to access this URL, you can use `look up` activity to access the URL anywhere required.
- I have used `utcNow()` to generate `dateToken`. But if you have any specific date in mind, you can simply use that in the correct format (in place of utcNow()).

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Thank you so much for below. I will try this and confirm you. Please correct me if I'm incorrect. I thought tokens came from APIs when a request is made. How are you able to generate a Token & DateToken without even hitting an API URL?

Comment: The python code you provided is not getting the tokens from API but is generating the tokens using code (without API) and then making a call to URL after building it. I have taken the logic from your python code and implemented it in ADF and built the URL (same as in the python code). Correct me if I misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: Thanks Saideep. Your understanding is correct. I will try the answer you suggested and confirm.

Comment: I have posted another query related to using lookup activity, Could you please help me out on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363693/azure-data-factory-lookup-activity

Comment: Can you please clarify this: You have mentioned that single quotes are but working and that is the only significant difference between the working query and query with dynamic content

Comment: Hi Saideep, Issue is resolved now. Only difference is I didn't include single quotes to one of the parameter when using dynamic query. Its all good now, thank you!

Comment: Regarding, this query as the TTL is valid for 1 year. Can I generate data token and token once and use it for a year? I don't want to fetch date token and token every time I hit the API, instead generate the date token and token once and use it for an year

Comment: Hey @VivekKB, I have updated the answer to generate date token only once and save final URL to file. You can simply use look up to get read this file and access the final URL.