# Azure Data Factory - Lookup Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm calling a procedure using a lookup activity in Azure Data Factory.
***NOTE:*** The reason to use Lookup here is, I wanted to store the OUTPUT parameter value from procedure into a variable in ADF for future use.

**Below works,**

```
DECLARE @ADFOutputMsg [VARCHAR](500);
EXEC Test.spAsRunTVA @ReportDate = '2022-06-01', @OutputMsg = @ADFOutputMsg OUTPUT;
SELECT @ADFOutputMsg As OutputMsg;
```

[image: Works]

**But when I want to pass dynamic parameters, it doesn't like,**

```
DECLARE @ADFOutputMsg [VARCHAR](500);
EXEC @{pipeline().parameters.SchemaName}.spAsRunTVA @ReportDate = @{substring(pipeline().parameters.FileName,8,10)}, @OutputMsg = ADFOutputMsg OUTPUT;
SELECT @ADFOutputMsg As OutputMsg;
```

[image: Doesn't Work]

**I also tried to keep the date As-Is and just updated SchemaName to be dynamic but I still get the error.**

[image: Change]
[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

Please Provide single quote `' '` at your dynamic content

`'@{substring(pipeline().parameters.FileName,8,10)}'`

**I tried to reproduce similar kind of approach in my environment and I got below results:**

Use the below dynamic content in the query with lookup activity.  and also Added dynamic content with single quotes `' '`

```
select * from for_date where date1='@{string(pipeline().parameters.Date)}'
```

[image]

Added **`Date`** Parameter

[image]

**Got this Output:**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I still, get error. Are you able to exactly replicate my query and try this out?